# How to save the position of draggable elements?

Tags: javascript, html, django

Hello, I am making a web application in django, what it allows you to do is drag elements on the page, what I want to do is save the position of these elements so that when the page is reloaded the elements remain in the same position in which they left, is there any way to save the position?

**This is my javascript to drag elements.**

```
<script src="http://threedubmedia.com/inc/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://threedubmedia.com/inc/js/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('.drag')
            .click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("selected");
            })
            .drag("init", function () {
                if ($(this).is('.selected'))
                    return $('.selected');
            })
            .drag(function (ev, dd) {
                $(this).css({
                    top: dd.offsetY,
                    left: dd.offsetX
                });
            });
    });
```

**And this is the element or elements that are dragged, the number of elements is variable since it is conditioned by a database.**

```
<div class="drag">
                    <span class="dot" title="{{ device.device_name }}" style="background-color: #197f32"><br/><b><p
                            style="color: #ce3830;"> {{ device.device_name }}</p></b></span>
                </div>
```

Comment: As soon as the user stops the dragging, you could post an AJAX request that contains the current coordinates on the screen to a url that is connected to a view that handles the post request and saves the coordinates for that user in a Model.

Comment: ON mouse up save coordinates in local storage with id of element, then on reload call it and apply it. You have not provided [mre] in order to make example.